# can a compact set have infinite measure?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Can a compact set have infinite measure? It does not seem to violate the measure axioms.

This is not true in the case of Lebesgue measure. So I am also wondering is there any clean cut condition for this to hold or not.

Comment: It can. Take the counting measure on $[0, 1]$ for example.

Comment: Not sure about conditions for it to hold, but a measure that assigns finite mass to compact sets is usually called a _Radon measure_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not? Let $X=[0,1]$ and define $$\mu(E)=\begin{cases}|E|&\text{if $|E|$ is finite}\\\infty&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$